# Angular Material - Expand button to parent's width

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to make my md-button has the same width as its parent div but I don't have any idea of how. Now, gets the width of its content.

```
<div class="margin-div">
  <md-button type="submit" flex="100" class="md-raised md-primary">Log in</md-button>
  </div>
```

css

```
.margin-div{
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

Comment: try giving width 100% to md-button instead of flex

Comment: Worked... No I am confused about flex utility....

Comment: @SatpalTanan Thank you for the answer. It worked. I did not understand how part. Would u like to explain please?